# React Component re-renders in iOS but not in Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, refresh, usecallback

I am developing an app using React Native and I'm struggling to figure out why my component re-renders in iOS but not in Android. I'm expecting it not to re-render, which means that the Android behavior is the one I'm looking for. The problem is, I don't want this `headerIcons` to be re-rendered. I've tried `useCallback`, `useMemo`, `React.memo` but it keeps refreshing in iOS devices...

The re-rendering part is the `headerIcons` argument inside the `headerRightIcons` parameter of the `<Header.NoTitle>` component. And here is the thing, this `<Header.NoTitle>` shows two icons on the screen, one is the `< goBack` button and the other is the `? help center` button (the headerRightIcons parameter) but the only icon being re-rendered is the `?` icon. The other one stays fixed.

All the components are being wrapped in a Pull-to-refresh scheme, but the requisition is only being made inside the last Container. Which means that the only part of the screen I wanted to be refreshed is the Container.

```
const headerIcons = useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                icon: 'question-circle',
                onPress: () =>
                    goToSection(
                        navigation as never,
                        EnumInvoiceMainScreenArrivedFrom.MyInvoices,
                    ),
            },
        ],
        [navigation],
    );

    
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <ScrollView
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl onRefresh={onRefresh} refreshing={isRefresh} />
                }
                stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
            >
                <HeaderContainer>
                    <Header.NoTitle onBackPress={goBack} headerRightIcons={headerIcons} />
                    <Title>{t(`${i18nPrefix}.title`)}</Title>

                    <TabRender
                        tabs={tabsToRender}
                        tabIndex={tabIndex}
                        onTabSelected={setTabIndex}
                    />
                </HeaderContainer>

                <Container flex={1} key={`list-updated-${refreshCounter}-times`}>
                    {children}
                </Container>
            </ScrollView>
        </Wrapper>
    );
};
```

Comment: Which component is re-rendering and when exactly?

Comment: The re-rendering part is the `headerIcons` argument inside the `headerRightIcons` parameter of the <Header.NoTitle> component. And here is the thing, this <Header.NoTitle> shows two icons on the screen, one is the `<` goBack button and the other is the `?` help center button (the headerRightIcons parameter). The only icon being re-rendered is the `?`icon. The other one stays fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Does the same thing happen if you do it like this?

```
const handleRightIconPress = ()=>{
   goToSection(navigation, EnumInvoiceMainScreenArrivedFrom.MyInvoices)
}
```

```
<Header.NoTitle onBackPress={goBack} 
    headerRightIcons={{
       icon: 'question-circle',
       onPress: handleRightIconPress,
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: Yes, it does... Although your solution is something I haven't tried yet, the moment I tried it the same unnecessary re-rendering kept happening. But hey, can't say how much I appreciate your time invested here! =)

Comment: have you tried removing onPress completely, just to narrow down the reasons